Expected pressure on water heater drain?
A plumber put a water pressure gauge on my water heater's drain spout, opened the valve, and then proclaimed that my pressure was crazy high and thus my pressure regulator was bad at my main water inlet. This kind of seemed strange to me because I always felt like my shower pressure was actually on the low side.
What do you expect the pressure should read in a healthy system for a 40 gallon water tank, not drained and fully heated?
Is this an accurate way to diagnose the pressure regulator at the inlet supply to my home?

did they actually say the pressure? and is your expansion tank working properly?

Do you have a well or are you on a municipal water supply? If you are on city water then you have no control over the pressure. The flow is probably more what you are concerned with in the shower not the pressure since the pressure at a spigot drops to zero when the valve is opened. Pressure causes flow through the resistance of the piping.

I am on municipal water supply. He didn't specifically say what the pressure meter read, but I have just purchased one for myself and should arrive today. In terms of expansion tank, I had my entire water heater replaced by a plumber just a couple weeks ago, including the expansion tank, and the installation passed my county's inspection.

It should be normal house pressure plus a few pounds.  Anything over 80 pounds is a bit concerning for house water pipes.  Can get a pressure gauge yourself and find the pressure.

I do plan on measuring it myself. If it's high, can I just adjust the pressure regulator (I see it has a screw protruding out), or is it time for a replacement?

I would agree with crip659. Most well systems operate between 40 to 60 PSI. But if you are not having any problems and the system is working as expected then ignore the plumber.

Either it's high and you can adjust it, or it's high and the pressure regulator needs rebuit or replaced (whether it can be rebuilt depends on if the seals are bad (rebuid) or if the parts of the body they seal against are damaged (replace) and whether you can find a rebuild kit for significantly less than  whole new regulator (which sometimes leans towards replace the whole thing anyway, if the economics are being weird.) Or the plumber was BS-ing you (not showing you the reading is suspicious.)

Well that does seem an unusual place to measure water pressure, but it would be the same pressure that you would see at any other outlet (like on a hose bib)

On a water supply where you need a PRV, you really should just invest (once) in having a gauge on the supply and a gauge after the PRV (permanently) so you can easily check that things are as they should be. On a well system normally the one gauge permanently mounted near the pressure switch is adequate, though having an additional one in a convenient location is not a bad thing and does not cost much..
